# XCode 4 - linker errors

Tags: linker, xcode4

After having upgraded to XCode 4 im getting some linker warnings that Im a bit baffled about.

My first 2 linker warnings are related to InMobi libraries (an Ads provider).
These warnings are complaining about a Directory that can't be found.
The only thing I can see is that perhaps "Xcode" doesn't like a directory path with a "../" in it.

The "library search paths" look correct.
\"$(SRCROOT)/../AdUtilities/AdProviders/InMobi/iPhone_3.x\"

Note that the SRCRoot (the App folder) is a sibling (the same folder location) as the Adutilities folder. What could be it's problem???

*** updated ***

I tried providing the full library path, but still same warnings.

*** updated 2 ***

the ad provider causing the link issues was InMobi.
I removed all references to InMobi, now things are building without warnings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*** Updated ***

This was causing more problems that what it was worth. I just removed InMobi as one of my ad providers. now everything builds with errors or warnings.